# Python+BeautifulSoup: scraping a particular table from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a particular table from :
[this webpage](http://biz.yahoo.com/c/s.html)

What I want to scrape is the stock information. The dates, company name, ratio and whether or not it is optionable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://biz.yahoo.com/c/s.html"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

alltables = soup.find_all('table')
```

This code gives me all the tables on the page (there is more than one).

1) I'm not sure how to identify the table that I need.

2) I'm not sure how to extract the info from that table into an array or list or some other data structure I can use for further analysis.

Comment: How can we know what you need if you yourself don't know?

Comment: Your intended table is the last table in body tag. try `soup.find_all("table")[-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The markup is not exactly easy to scrape - there are no `id`s or specific `class` attributes that you can use to distinguish the tables from one another. What I would do in this case is to *find a `Payable` header cell and find the first `table` [parent](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent)*:

```
header = soup.find("b", text="Payable")
table = header.find_parent("table")
```

Then, you can iterate over table rows skipping the first 2 - header and the row with the divider:

```
for row in table.find_all("tr")[2:]:
    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

And, you can transform it into a list of lists:

```
[[cell.get_text(strip=True) 
  for cell in row.find_all("td")]
 for row in table.find_all("tr")[2:]]
```

Comment: To anyone who is struggling to get this answer to work as I just was, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753775/web-scrapeing-a-table-to-a-list) to my question helpful, even if the question I lead with is pretty rubbish. It uses a different approach as my table wasn't playing ball.