# Web-scrapeing a table to a list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract a table from a webpage. I have managed to get all the data in the table into a list. However all the table data is being put into one list element. I need assistance getting the 'clean' data (i.e. the strings, without all the HTML packaging) from the rows of the table into their own list elements.

So instead of...

```
list  = [<tr>
         <th><a href="/7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS" title="7.62x25mm TT AKBS"><img alt="TTAKBS.png" decoding="async" height="64" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/escapefromtarkov_gamepedia/images/6/61/TTAKBS.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/64?cb=20190519001904" width="64"/></a>
         </th>
         <th><a href="/7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS" title="7.62x25mm TT AKBS">7.62x25mm TT AKBS</a>
         </th>
         <td>58
         </td>
         <td>12
         </td>
         <td>32]
```

I would like...

```
list  = ['href="/7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS" title="7.62x25mm TT AKBS"><img alt="TTAKBS.png" decoding="async" height="64" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/escapefromtarkov_gamepedia/images/6/61/TTAKBS.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/64?cb=20190519001904" width="64"',
         'href="/7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS" title="7.62x25mm TT AKBS">7.62x25mm TT AKBS',
         '58',
         '12',
         '32']
```

My code and `list` can be replicated using the following.

```
#Import Modules
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Get page
cartridge_url = 'https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/7.62x25mm_Tokarev'
cartridge_page = requests.get(cartridge_url)
cartridge_soup = BeautifulSoup(cartridge_page.content, 'html.parser')

#This gets the rows of the table I want
list = cartridge_soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name =='tr')

#This gets rid of an element which is not useful
list = [n for n in dirty_temp_type if not 'class="va-navbox' in str(n)]

#I had hoped this might assemble a list..  
list = [str(n) for n in list]
```

---

I'm learning python, I think I grasp HTML, but I cannot get python to interact with my `bs4.element.ResultSet`. I know this is not a sophisticated solution but I have hit a brick wall after trying a number of different approaches. My 'true' end goal is a list like the following...

```
list  = ['7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS',
         '58',
         '12',
         '32']
```

---

**Attempts to Implement Suggested Solutions:**

---> As suggested by [AzyCrw4282](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505847/azycrw4282)

*That's an incredible username btw.*

**(i)**

I [think I] can see roughly what I'm supposed to do but I'm failing to properly implement it.

Using...

```
cartridge_table = cartridge_soup.find_all('table')
```

I get what looks to be all the right data in HTML format stored inside `cartridge_table`. However, running...

```
for row in cartridge_table.find_all("tr")[:1]:
    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

...returns...

```
ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

... and replacing `find_all` with `find` doesn't remedy the issue.

**(ii)**

I half-heartedly ran...

```
for row in cartridge_soup.find_all("tr")[:1]:
    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

...but this returns an empty list.

**(iii)**

The question you originally linked to defines a variable called `header` prior to filling the `table` variable with the necassary data...

```
header = soup.find("b", text="Payable")
table = header.find_parent("table")
```

I'm not grasping what to replace "Payable" with to get this to work for me.

**(iv)**

I tried to negate the above problem in *(iii)* by giving this a stab...

```
cartridge_table = cartridge_soup.find_parent("table")

for row in cartridge_soup.find_all("tr")[:1]:
    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

But it returns an empty list. When I checked it's because nothing gets stored under the `cartridge_table` variable.

**(V)**

I tried running...

```
header = cartridge_soup.find("b", text="Payable")
```

... and replacing `"Payable"` with a variety of seemingly sensible alternatives to see what would happen, but I got nowhere. Ultimately the `header` variable always seemed to remain empty.

Examples: `"Icon"`, `"Name"`, `"Fragmentation Chance"`, `"wikitable sortable"`, `"7.62x25mm TT LRN"`, `"7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS"`.

Comment: Don’t name your variables `list`, you’re overriding the build in `list` function.

Comment: why would you want only part of the img tag? And why as html?

Comment: I got pulled away but I will return to my work soon. I'll update ASAP and I won't just leave you hanging. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I have attempted to implement your solution. If when you are next free you could offer some advice I would be very grateful.

Comment: send it away... I am always around here

Comment: I have added it to the bottom of the original question - 'Attempts to Implement Suggested Solutions:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played around to solve the problem but there seems to be something wrong with the table given on the page — at least that's what I think. The extraction of the table should yield elements of size `n` for the given number of rows but for some reason, it gives all of the rows as a single element in the array. I did look into but didn't get far with this(and I am also short of time).

Given that you are only interested in the cells in the first rows then in this case you can easily do it by targetting those elements with the `XPath` approach. This will easily locate the elements and yield the values you require. `Xpath` however doesn't work with `BeautifulSoup`.

To solve this problem, I ended up using a hardcoded approach to select the required elements in the array. This targets the first extraction of the `name` column, followed by the other columns.

Code

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

#Get page
cartridge_url = 'https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/7.62x25mm_Tokarev'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(cartridge_url)
cartridge_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
tables = cartridge_soup.findChildren('table')
my_table = tables[0]

cartridge_table = my_table.findChildren(['table','th', 'tr'])
dataArray = []
dataArray.append(str(cartridge_table[13]).split('</a>')[0][45:62].replace(" ","_"))
splitChar = str(cartridge_table[13]).split("</td>")

for data in splitChar[:3]:
    dataArray.append(data[-3:-1])

print(dataArray)
```

Gives

```
['7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS', '58', '12', '32']
```

Let me know if it solves your problem or if it needs adapting for other use cases.

Comment: Holy smokes, thank you so much. I'm going to mess around with extracting different stuff and try to properly get to grips with what you have provided me with. It looks like it will be the swiss army knife for all my EFT-wiki scraping needs. If I need any help I will tag you but I'm going to mark it as correct here and now because it's a great answer and you've really helped me. If you are too busy in the near future to respond don't sweat it, you've already gone above and beyond. Many thanks. I would never have figured this out independently.

Comment: I am often busy but I always end up here at some point in the day, so I will definitely reply sooner or later. Feel free to ask, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding there's no way to parse this

```
list  = [<tr>
         <th><a href="/7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS" title="7.62x25mm TT AKBS"><img alt="TTAKBS.png" decoding="async" height="64" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/escapefromtarkov_gamepedia/images/6/61/TTAKBS.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/64?cb=20190519001904" width="64"/></a>
         </th>
         <th><a href="/7.62x25mm_TT_AKBS" title="7.62x25mm TT AKBS">7.62x25mm TT AKBS</a>
         </th>
         <td>58
         </td>
         <td>12
         </td>
         <td>32]
```

to your intended format. There may be a way to do it using `regex` but this overly complicates it.

The problem though can be solved using other methods. Also, it is not possible to locally debug your code since you haven't defined what `dirty_temp_type` is [This was an error in variable naming which has since been corrected]. In addition(as already mentioned in the comment), do not use `list` as a variable name, since that can invoke the built-in definition of `list` and can cause errors.

There's a perfect answer here - [Python+BeautifulSoup: scraping a particular table from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664249/pythonbeautifulsoup-scraping-a-particular-table-from-a-webpage) - and this shows you exactly what you need to do.

Code snippett from the mentioned link

```
for row in table.find_all("tr")[:1]:
    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

Using this would fetch the data from the cells of the first row and will give you the output of your end-goal in a list.